# Why does changing picturebox size mode remove drawn graphics?

Tags: vb.net, graphics, picturebox

So I currently have this working code on a picturebox called pbZoneImage:

```
        'draw rect
        Dim control As Control = CType(pbZoneImage, Control)
        Dim g As Graphics = Me.pbZoneImage.CreateGraphics()
        pbZoneImage.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        If camRect1 <> Nothing Then g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, camRect1)
        If camRect2 <> Nothing Then g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Coral, camRect2)
        If camRect3 <> Nothing Then g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Yellow, camRect3)

        'update
        pbZoneImage.Update()
```

The line that concerns me is the StretchImage. No matter what where I put it in the code, it causes my drawn rectangles to not show up. If I remove it, they show up perfectly (but not in the stretched image format).

While I could live without it being stretched, my curious question is why does this remove the boxes? I would understand if I did it *after* I had drawn the rectangles or even after I declare the control. But why does it still affect it before all of this?

Note: I have stepped through, and it is running each line without a error.

**Update:** To clarify, this code is within a button click event. I want it to draw rectangles on the picturebox when I click the button.

**UPDATE:**
Using the things mentioned from others in the comment, apparently createGraphics() is not a very reliable method. Instead you should draw on the bitmap itself and display that. That is what I ended up doing, with success!

```
        Dim imageFile As Image = pbZoneImage.Image

       'Show Rectangles on Picture box 
        Dim newGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imageFile)

        Dim redPen As New Pen(Brushes.Red, 5)
        Dim bluePen As New Pen(Brushes.Blue, 5)
        Dim yellowPen As New Pen(Brushes.Yellow, 5)

        'draw
        If camRect1 <> Nothing Then newGraphics.DrawRectangle(redPen, camRect1)
        If camRect2 <> Nothing Then newGraphics.DrawRectangle(bluePen, camRect2)
        If camRect3 <> Nothing Then newGraphics.DrawRectangle(yellowPen, camRect3)

        'show new drawn on image
        pbZoneImage.Image = imageFile

        'stretch image 
        pbZoneImage.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
```

Comment: where is that code located?  we have no context but I would think `.Update` is what is removing the rects, if there is no code in paint to redraw then rects they should disappear

Comment: Hmm.. Update is still there when I remove that line of code, but I will try it the other way! The code is located in a button click event, and I will include that info in the question.

Comment: Well, without update() but with stretchimage the boxes are shown, but the image isn't stretched. After this code it literally is "End Sub", so there's nothing else to touch it. Interesting.

Comment: the image is not stretched because there is no image!  `CreateGraphics` is almost always the wrong way to draw something - it wont be redrawn when the region is invalidated.  DrawRect does not add anything to the picBox Image - that would be the job of your code.  IF you want the rects to stretch, draw the rects on the picbox image (and/or create one to draw on)

Comment: What you draw will immediately be erased again.  Because you used CreateGraphics() and gave the PictureBox a reason to repaint by changing SizeMode.  CreateGraphics is wrong in 99.9% of all cases, use Graphics.FromImage() instead to make it last.  Or the Paint event if you don't actually want to change the image.

Comment: I do want to be able to change the image. So I guess From Image() is the way I will go!